# Is there a way to avoid deleting a branch in Azure DevOps without obliging pull requests?

Tags: azure-devops, git

In Azure DevOps, configuring a branch policy ensures the branch cannot be deleted. However this also obliges to use pul requests to make changes to that branch.

Currently we are not using pull requests yet, but we still would like to prevent certain branches from getting deleted.

Is there a way to do that other than branch policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the "Force Push" permission, it will block users from deleting the branch.

The "Force Push" permission...

> Can force an update to a branch, delete a branch, and modify the commit history of a branch. Can delete tags and notes.

See [more on these permissions on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002938).

Comment: Thx! Works like a charm. Probably beginner questions but just learning Azure DevOps.

Comment: No question is a bad question. I'm glad it helped.